# How to make a range bar chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts, range

Hey I'm new to forums and this is my first post. I am new to vba in excel, but have written thinkscript in ThinkorSwim.

If anyone is familiar with a range stock chart, thats what Im going after.

I found code for a line chart, and am using it, but it is based on where price is at any given time. I want to modify this line chart to only plot values when they are above or below a range so that it resembles a candlestick chart with no wicks. Once data enters that range, I only want it to update whenever a new high or low is made in that range. The ranges need to be preset (ex. 50 ticks) Once the range is exceeded, I want the data plotted in the next range up, and repeat the process. Time and dates should be ignored, and only plot based on price action.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
Option Explicit

'Update the values between the quotes here:
Private Const sChartWSName = "Chart"
Private Const sSourceWSName = "Sheet1"
Private Const sTableName = "tblValues"
Public RunTime As Double

Private Sub Chart_Setup()
'Create the structure needed to preserve and chart data
    Dim wsChart As Worksheet
    Dim lstObject As ListObject
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim shp As Button
    'Create sheet if necessary
    Set wsChart = Worksheets.Add
    wsChart.Name = sChartWSName
    'Set up listobject to hold data
    With wsChart
        .Range("A1").Value = "Time"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Value"
        Set lstObject = .ListObjects.Add( _
                        SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
                        Source:=.Range("A1:B1"), _
                        xllistobjecthasheaders:=xlYes)
        lstObject.Name = sTableName
        .Range("A2").NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM (mmm-d)"
        .Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 25
        .Select
    End With
    'Create the chart
    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes.AddChart.Select
        Set cht = ActiveChart
        With cht
            .ChartType = xlLine
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range(sTableName)
            .PlotBy = xlColumns
            .Legend.Delete
            .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
            With .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Range
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .Weight = 1.25
            End With
        End With
    End With
    'Add buttons to start/stop the routine
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(242.25, 0, 83.75, 33.75)
    With shp
        .OnAction = "Chart_Initialize"
        .Characters.Text = "Restart Plotting"
    End With
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(326.25, 0, 83.75, 33.75)
    With shp
        .OnAction = "Chart_Stop"
        .Characters.Text = "Stop Plotting"
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub Chart_Initialize()
'Initialize the routine
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim lstObject As ListObject

'Make sure worksheet exists
On Error Resume Next
Set wsTarget = Worksheets(sChartWSName)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Call Chart_Setup
    Set wsTarget = Worksheets(sChartWSName)
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Check if chart data exists
With Worksheets(sChartWSName)
    Set lstObject = .ListObjects(sTableName)
    If lstObject.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        Select Case MsgBox("You already have data.  Do you want to clear it and start fresh?", vbYesNoCancel, "Clear out old data?")

            Case Is = vbYes
                'User wants to clear the data
                lstObject.DataBodyRange.Delete

            Case Is = vbCancel
                'User cancelled so exit routine
                Exit Sub

            Case Is = vbNo
                'User just wants to append to existing table
        End Select
    End If

    'Begin appending
    Call Chart_AppendData
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Chart_AppendData()
'Append data to the chart table
Dim lstObject As ListObject
Dim lRow As Long

With Worksheets(sChartWSName)
    Set lstObject = .ListObjects(sTableName)
    If lstObject.ListRows.Count = 0 Then
        lRow = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    End If
    If lRow = 0 Then
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End If
    If lRow > 2 Then
        If .Range("B" & lRow - 1).Value = Worksheets(sSourceWSName).Range("C10").Value Then
            'Data is a match, so do nothing
        Else
            'Data needs appending
            .Range("A" & lRow).Value = CDate(Now)
            .Range("B" & lRow).Value = Worksheets(sSourceWSName).Range("C10").Value
        End If
    Else
            'Data needs appending
            .Range("A" & lRow).Value = CDate(Now)
            .Range("B" & lRow).Value = Worksheets(sSourceWSName).Range("C10").Value
    End If
End With

RunTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime RunTime, "Chart_AppendData"
End Sub

Public Sub Chart_Stop()
'Stop capturing data
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunTime, Procedure:="Chart_AppendData", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: One way that works for me, when modifying ranges for charts, is to filter the contents.  When you set the range for the chart, you would A) filter the sheet, B) select range based on your parameters, C) output in a chart.  Filtering/hiding will make line items not be visible in the chart.

Comment: Can you show an example please?

Comment: Im trying to upload the chart to show you what I got, but cant figure out how to do it

Comment: If youve got some code can you upload that please?  You can edit it into your question

Comment: Ive added the code to the original question. Thank you for the interest!

Answer (score 0):

Take your sheet of data and filter... example would be:

```
Columns("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("C2"), _
  order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlYes
```

Sort info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx

You then can define to select your desired range.  Assuming column A is x-axis and B is y-axis (where your parameters for modifying need to be assessed):

```
Dim High1 as integer
Dim Low1 as integer

High1 = Match(Max(B:B),B:B)  'This isn't tested, just an idea
Low1 = Match(Max(B:B)+50,B:B)  'Again, not tested
```

and using those defined parameters:

```
.Range(Cells(High1,1),Cells(Low1,2).Select
```

This should give an idea for High1/Low1, where you can work through how you want to define the row that the max value occurs.

You then CreateObject for the Chart you want, having selected the data range you are going to use.

Comment: Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
'Stop workbook refreshing

    Call Chart_Stop

End Sub

Comment: I still cant send all the code. It says its too many characters. Is there a way i can send them to you in a msg?

Comment: Ok I got the original code entered into the original question above. Where should I place the code that you sent?